# upgrading to php 5.3.6

Tags: php, mac-osx

I just upgraded to dev box to OSX Lion which has php 5.3.6 (from Snow Leopard).

Now my Yii made sites are broken.  How do I know what code is now broken with out finding them out one by one?  Why is the code below broken?  Is there something that I can turn on in the php.ini files to overcome these things?  I need to get back to work but don't want to just go back to Snow Leopard to do so.  Would appreciate help / guidance.

Here are some of the following errors:

***Use of undefined constant style - assumed 'style'  on***

```
'htmlOptions'=>array(style=>'cursor: pointer;'),
```

*Fixed by enclosing 'style'*

```
'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'cursor: pointer;'),
```

***Trying to get property of non-object (Within CJuiTabs) on***

`'Title' =>$this->renderPartial("_details", array('model' => $model), $this),`

*Not sure how to fix this one*

***Use of undefined constant Y - assumed 'Y' (Within CGridView dataprovider) on***

```
$dataProvider = 
    new CActiveDataProvider('Bus', array(
          'criteria'=>array(
               'with' => array(
                  'address' => array(
                        'on'=>'busAddresses.Id='.$model->Id.' 
                               AND busAddresses.IsPhysical="'.Y.'"',
```

*Not sure how to fix this one*

Comment: Broken how? The behavior leading to these messages is the same in PHP 5.3.6 as it was in whatever version of PHP Snow Leopard had (I know it was in the 5.3 series). In particular, all three are *notices*, not errors. The undefined constant ones at least are harmless (though they should still be fixed), and wouldn't by themselves be causing the site to be "broken". (Unless, of course, `display_errors` is on and the notice output is preventing headers from being sent).

Comment: @John Flatness, I thought SL was in 5.3 also and was just trying to look that up.  These errors or notices are blocking the page from being rendered but they were not before the upgrade.  I compared the php.ini files but could not find the difference there to cause this.  I did not have problems going from Leopard (PHP 5.2 I though) to Snow but now I am experiencing these problems with this upgrade.

Comment: @John Flatness, I checked the display_errors value in this build and it is set to off.

Comment: The thing is, if display_errors is set to off, you wouldn't see these messages you've posted, unless you're reading them out of a log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've implied elsewhere that you're getting more error messages than the few you posted, I'm going to assume that one of the errors you didn't post was something like this:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent

Since the underlying causes of all these messages you're seeing isn't any different under your new version of PHP, a configuration setting is likely to blame for the difference. In particular, the `display_errors` setting, which simply controls whether the messages about all the errors, warnings and notices will be printed to the screen.

Apple's default php.ini file sets display_errors to Off, but you need to move the /etc/php.ini.default to /etc/php.ini to have that file take any effect. /etc/php.ini isn't carried over in an OS X upgrade, so it would make sense that you lost this setting.

Comment: thanks for the feedback.  I have not seen that Warning yet, but then again I can not navigate through most of my site right now with what is going on.  I commented above about the display_errors.  It comes set to off.

Comment: I did `sudo cp /etc/php.ini.default /etc/php.ini` after the upgrade too so it is using this file

Comment: OK did some more digging.  I change `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED` to `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE` and this was what was doing it.  Guess the good thing that came of this was it brought some coding changes that should be done to my attention.

Comment: As a rule it's a good idea to have E_ALL (or even E_STRICT) on your dev environment and have errors turned off on your production environment. (I'm not sure how some of that code wasn't breaking stuff b4.)

Answer (score 1):

```
 AND busAddresses.IsPhysical="'.Y.'"',
```

`Y` is a string in your case, so use it as a string:

```
 AND busAddresses.IsPhysical="Y"',
```

Comment: Making that change within the code posted in the question does not work.  Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: @enfield: "doesn't work" explains nothing. Do you still have the same error message?

Comment: Scratch my comment.  I thought the same error was appearing but I had another instance below on that same file that was causing the same error.  Thanks for the help.